# Where is .Net Looking For My Config File?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7, configuration-files

I have a WCF ASP.Net 4.0 web service we'll call "WebService". WebService is consuming a class library assembly we'll call "WebServiceClassLibrary". WebServiceClassLibrary is referencing another class library assembly ("ExternalClassLibrary"). ExternalClassLibrary is built to use a configuration file. It uses this file to learn where it is to be sending some HTTP posts at runtime. I'm having a problem where no matter where I seem to put the configuration section for ExternalClassLibrary it seems to be using the default configuration (a behavior I have come to expect when it cannot find a config file at runtime).

I expect this means that when .Net is attempting to find the configuration for ExternalClassLibrary it is unable to do so and uses the configuration information found in the compiled assembly. I have attempted to override this configuration by placing a configuration section in the web.config file for WebService, by creating a config file for ExternalClassLibrary and by creating a config file for WebServiceClassLibrary. Even if I attempt to override the configuration in each of these places it still ends up using the default configuration. I am hosting the site in IIS 7.

Can someone please tell me how I can determine where I need to place this overriding configuration information? I have tried to use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see file system read attempts that fail but it only shows two possible places to override the configuration and neither of them did the trick.

Appreciate it!

-- UPDATE, Here is the contents of the XML file I am trying to load --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="MyAppName.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <applicationSettings>
        <MyAppName.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="APIURL" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://servername/default.html</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="APIAPPINI" serializeAs="String">
                <value>app.ini</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ApiUrlRoot" serializeAs="String">
                <value>https://www.domain.com/company[instance]test/index.htm</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ApiInstances" serializeAs="Xml">
                <value>
                    <ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                        <string>usa</string>
                        <string>eu</string>
                        <string>asia</string>
                        <string>lat</string>
                        <string>jpn</string>
                    </ArrayOfString>
                </value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ApiKey" serializeAs="String">
                <value>password</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ApiUrlRoot" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://site[instance].domain.com/</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ProductId" serializeAs="String">
                <value>12345</value>
            </setting>
        </MyAppName.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Not sure if it'll help you, but I had a similar question about config files for class libraries a while back.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2526202/where-are-config-files-for-class-libraries-physically-located

Comment: Most posts on that page talk about the config file being used from the parent or consuming app. This is what I have found to be true in the past but for some reason it's not happening now. Seems unreliable. WebService is the consuming application but adding the configuration to that file doesn't result in updated values being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer (as my question was worded) is actually in the question itself

> I have attempted to override this configuration by placing a configuration section in the
>   web.config file...

In .Net when an assembly is being consumed, the framework looks to the configuration in the consuming assembly's config file. So that is the answer to the question. This is where I have learned to place configuration information for assemblies in past but in this instance this method seemed to be failing me.

The reason I was having no luck in this case with the web.config file overriding the default configuration is due to a bug in my code where when actually attempting to request the value in the config file I was explicitly requesting the "DefaultValue" which will always be what is found in the compiled assembly.

The code was like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties["ApiUrlRoot"].DefaultValue;
```

I didn't realize while I was developing that this would be the case. I had to trial and error it to get the value while indexing into Properties instead of the standard strongly-typed method for reading values:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ApiUrlRoot;
```

This is because this portion of my code had to read the value from the config file dynamically. Depending on the situation it would read a different value from the config file. In the end here is the version of the dynamic config reading code that works:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.PropertyValues["ApiUrlRoot"].PropertyValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

Your ExternalClassLibrary should load the config as

```
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("ExternalClassLibrary.dll.config");
```

.Net ConfigManager by default loads only the main process config(exe.config/web.config), any dll using dll.config should load explicitly.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Appreciate it!

Comment: Ok I must have spoke too soon. It loads the config file, HasFile is true and it even shows the path as the config file as being the correct file, but if i look closer I see there aren't any applicationSettings loaded. This, even though there are applicationSettings in the loaded config file. I'm thinking the problem is that it will only load the applicationSettings if it knows the configSection I want to load but I can't figure out how to tell it that and a quick google search on the subject doesn't shed any light. Any idea?

Comment: Can you post the section of xml

Comment: certainly, I modified my original post to contain the xml

Comment: This ended up not being what I was looking for. I did some more in-depth debugging with Fiddler and found the answer. (posting below)